# CSS styles not working while included in .info.yml file

Tags: javascript, theming, 8

For some reason my theme can't find css/style.css in Drupal 8.

This is the .info.yml:

```
name: Adminimal
type: theme
description: Drupal Administration Simplified.
# version: VERSION
# core: 8.x
base theme: seven

# Include CSS.
 stylesheets:
  all:
   - css/style.css

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2014-10-23
version: '8.x-1.x-dev'
core: '8.x'
project: 'adminimal_theme'
datestamp: 1414059738
```

This is how the folders look like:

```
Theme/adminimal.info.yml
Theme/css/style.css
```

The css in the style.css file:

```
html{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

It doesn't even show up in the styles section in my Google Chrome console so I think it doesn't find the file but why?

And about jQuery in Drupal, I can't manage to get this working: https://www.drupal.org/node/1541860 To work with: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js How should I do this?

Comment: This is asking 2 questions in one so I'm ignoring the jQuery one, post a separate question for that. The .info.yml in the question doesn't even parse, YAML is whitespace sensitive: `Drupal\Core\Extension\InfoParserException: Unable to parse themes/adminimal_theme/adminimal.info.yml: Unable to parse at line 9 (near " stylesheets:")`, so make sure your whitespace lines up. stylesheets has an extra leading space and the line declaring style.css is indented by one space too many (it will probably forgive you for that though).

Answer (score 1):

Working for me creating drupal8 theme using bartik theme as base theme. Successfully call the css file present in my custom theme. Hopes this will helps you.

```
name: Smart
type: theme
description: 'Smart business templates'
core: '8.x'
package: Custom
base theme: bartik
project: 'drupal'
stylesheets-remove:
 - colors.css
stylesheets-override:
 - css/colors.css
regions:
 header: Header
 primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
 help: Help
 featured: Featured
 content: Content
 sidebar_first: 'First sidebar'  
 sidebar_second: 'Second sidebar'
 triptych_first: 'Triptych first'
 triptych_middle: 'Triptych middle'
 triptych_last: 'Triptych last'
 footer_firstcolumn: 'Footer first column'
 footer_secondcolumn: 'Footer second column'
 footer_thirdcolumn: 'Footer third column'
 footer_fourthcolumn: 'Footer fourth column'
 footer: Footer

settings:
 shortcut_module_link: false
```

Also take reference from https://www.drupal.org/node/1876600

Comment: Allright thanks that worked! but When i edit the css now it still ends up with the old styles before the edit after a refresh of the page and save of the css file?

Comment: CSS compression and aggregation is enabled by default in Drupal 8, go to /admin/config/development/performance to disable it or better yet use the settings.local.php provided with core (see the bottom of settings.php and sites/example.settings.local.php).

Comment: Also: to just add a new stylesheet you shouldn't need to use stylesheets-override.